# Activity bugs for "seen" and "visited" in profile

Tags: bug, status-completed

There are two bugs that I've discovered when it comes to my activity. First, my account is barely a few hours old, yet my WebApps account says "3 days, 1 consecutive":

[image]

Second, and this one is even stranger, my account here on Meta.WebApps says that my last visit is *5 hours from now*:

[image]

Comment: Hah, looks like I'm from the future, too!